# Intellij not able to find changes made in dependency modules

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven project which has dependency on other Maven projects. I have managed to import those dependency modules via 'project structure' into my project. Able to mvn clean install and able to run the program. Also in my main project, if I were to 'command click ' on a file that is located in the dependency modules, it will nicely go to that .java file (instead of heading to the .class file).

But changes made under the dependency project does not reflect when I run the program. Re building or a new mvn install doesn't make any difference.

For example, I have tried just adding a new variable declaration in a class located in the dependency modules. This variable does not even exist when I run the program and check via debug.

Similarly created an entire method in a class inside the dependency module. 
That method doesn't exist either. When I mouse over a breakpoint I placed under this method, I get following message:

> No executable code found at line 112 in class com.name....

Information which may help.

This project was working fine without having to add these dependencies cos they existed as jar files as part of this project. Since I needed to make changes in those dependencies, I have removed those jar files 'via Project Structure' and instead imported those dependencies as modules 'via Project Structure'.

As mentioned above, this is working. I am able to build and launch the app. Just not able to see changes when I make them.

Another issue which surfaced and again I don't get it. There was a parameter which was not working on my main project (compilation was failing) until I made the change in my dependency. Now it is working fine in terms of compilation. But when I run it, under debug I get the correct param value, but after the next step, it just jumps to **InvocationTargetException**. Added short snippet on the code change below.

```
// Under Main Project
someMethod(Doable do){
    // do something
}

DoSomething doSomething = null;
someMethod(doSomething); // compilation error unless I implement Doable

// Under dependency
// implement Doable is the change which compiles now
class DoSomething implements Doable{ 
    //implement something
}
```

Added the project structure for reference. 
Please advice. Thank you.

```
MyMainProject
    mvn_structure
    pom.xml
MainDependency
    SubDependency1 
        mvn_structure
        pom.xml
    SubDependency2
        mvn_structure
        pom.xml
    SubDependency3
        mvn_structure
        pom.xml
    pom.xml
```

Comment: why can't you have pom that just includes `MyMainProject` and `MainDependency`, so that when there is change on `SubDependency*`, you would be able to include them on `MyMainProject` when you do `mvn clean install`?

Comment: @YogenRai I don't get what you mean. If you mean change from having individual  poms for sub dependencies and just have one for main dependency, am not gonna do that. This is a set of legacy stuff which am not gonna meddle with unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: i am asking to combine them into one, have another outer pom that basically wraps your `MyMainProject` and `MainDependency`. Take a look into this example, where outer pom is just binding inner modules https://github.com/YogenRaii/kraker-info

Comment: @YogenRai These set of dependencies are being used by other projects too. I get what you mean but not the solution I am looking for. This is more like an Intellij issue. Thanks.

Comment: If your project is maven project, then the dependencies should be defined in maven pom file, not via intellij project structure. Moreover, after changes are made in the other project, you need to build that project first so you have the changes in the jar in your repo before those changes are accessible to your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project relies on the dependency jars in your maven repo, not on the dependency source codes (the other projects). So in order to have your changes in the other project available to your project, you need to build the other projects first so that their jars in the repo are updated. Only then are those changes available to your project.